# MVC 4 Membership Extra Fields?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, asp.net-membership, asp.net-mvc-4

I will really appreciate if somebody can point me in the right direction.

I'm new to Membership in MVC 4 and most of the links I found in Google are for MVC3.

How can I store users information? In the default database there's a UserName field. Can I add extra fields (phone number, nickname, etc) or do I create a MyUser class and somehow I link the ID to the UserId from the Membership?

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Look into `Profile` stuff: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

MVC4 uses SimpleMembership.  This has quite a big difference from the traditional Membership system.

The way it works is that you create your own Users table, and then you tell SimpleMembership which fields in your Users table to use for it's own purposes.

If you look in the Filters/InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs, you will find a line that looks like this in the SimpleMembershipInitializer class.

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", 
   "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

Here, you change the fields "UserProfile" to match your table name, "UserId" to match your UserId column name, and "UserName" to match your username field.

Then, you can simply add whatever other fields you want to this table.

The problem here is that you make the same mistake many people do.  Membership is not about anything other than login credentials.  That's it.  It doesn't care about other fields, you put those in your own database and look them up based on user id.

Comment: Ok, membership doesn't care about additional fields. Then how to add them the right way after calling InitializeDatabaseConnection? (provide an example please).